# Why is BIGInteger in JAVA not responding for higher powers?

Tags: java, biginteger

When I try to find the value of a `BigInteger` data type for **2<sup>23,000</sup>**, I am not able to see the value.

However, for calculations up to **2<sup>22,000</sup>**, I could display the `BigInteger` value without any problems.

Is there any solution or reason for this?

Comment: Yes, I've got a suggestion.  Edit your question to include the actual code.  There's too many details that you've not provided in order to give you a good answer.

Comment: I don't respond to higher powers, either.  Fight the system, man!

Comment: Please provide details about the machine and jdk that you are using

Answer (score 8):

I tried the following in order to make a `BigInteger` representation of `2^23000`:

```
BigInteger bi = new BigInteger("2");
bi = bi.pow(23000);
System.out.println(bi);
```

And the number displayed was a very large number spanning 6925 digits. (I won't paste it here as it will span over 100 lines.)

This is with Java 6 SE version 1.6.0_12 in Windows XP.

According the API Specification, [`BigInteger`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html) is an arbitrary-precision integer value which means it should be able to cope with very large integer values.

Answer (score 4):

It works fine for me on GNU/Linux.  What do you mean you can't "display" it?  What's your code and what error/problem do you get?

Answer (score 1):

this limit for BigInteger is around 2^16 billion, though it has been noted that some functions don't behave correctly after about 2^2 billion.

My guess is that your console or IDE has problems displaying very long lines.

Comment: Eclipse Helios console can not display the 2^23000 correctly (blank).

Answer (score 0):

Do you need the whole thing?  There is also a BigInteger.modpow(power, modulus) method which raises the integer value to the specified power and returning result % modulus -- commonly used in cryptography.  This is also MUCH faster when dealing with very large exponents.